# Robust Positioning for Vertical Text

Tags: html, css, positioning

This is the design I am currently working on: http://alpha.bounde.co.uk

as you can see each of the ribbon boxes has the title of the box as vertical text (about, work, contact) and I am trying to find the best way to position them so I can have any text of any length and it will appear down the left hand side. At the moment longer text appears to the right as it is rotated from its center. The reason I want it to be done automatically and not just calculate the width is I am using google fonts (which is currently turned off) and if the font isnt loaded in then the text string will be longer / shorter than before and it will again fall out of position.

```
h2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #793F26;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    top: 100px;
    background: #fdfdfd;
    display: block;
}
```

this is the styling I am using for the H2 and there is nothing special in the HTML just the H2 inside a container div which has a border of 30px and a padding of 20px.

anyone have any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put your headings in a larger container element that's centered on the left border, and center the headings within it.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/sqh95/

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.heading-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

<div class="heading-wrapper">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like Danko's solution might be better, though, assuming it works.

Comment: This was the most robust solution for me. What I then did was put a span inside the h2 so the border would be dynamic depending on how long the text is.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to set `transform-origin` to something that doesn't change based on the content, such as `left top`.

You can then use `translateX(-100%)` to "shift" your content so that you're pivoting around the (fixed) top-right corner. This is easier to work with than trying to rotate around the (variable) top-right corner alone.

So your result would be something like:

```
transform-origin:left top;
transform:translate(X,Y) rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
```

Replace `translate(X,Y)` with the required movement to get the element in position down the left side - it's better to do this than to use `left` and `top`, because then it will look acceptable in browsers that don't support transforms.